# Retrieve the text content with bounds from PDF document using Pdfium library

Tags: pdf, chromium, pdfium

I tried to get the text content from PDF document with bounds using Pdfium but I could not found the respective API. The below API retrieve the text content alone.

**FPDFText_GetText**

Please let me know if any other possible way to retrieve the text content along with bounds using Pdfium.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FPDFText_CountRects` to get a count of bounding rect boxes then `FPDFText_GetRect` for each of those counted rects. You can then use `FPDFText_GetBoundedText` to retrieve the text inside the given bounding box.  The API docs for those are all inside `fpdf_text.h`